# Improving the lower bound $I(n^2) > \frac{2(q-1)}{q}$ when $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Define the *abundancy index*
$$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical *sum of divisors* of $x$.

Since $q$ is prime, we have the bounds
$$\frac{q+1}{q} \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1},$$
which implies, since $N$ is perfect, that
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1}.$$

We now prove the following claim:

> **CLAIM:** $$I(n^2) > \bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} + 1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)$$

**PROOF:**  We know that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^k) - q^k}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)),$$
(since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$).

However, we have
$$\sigma(q^k) - q^k = 1 + q + \ldots + q^{k-1} = \frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1},$$
so that we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{\bigg(q - 1\bigg)\bigg(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\bigg)}{q^k - 1}=\sigma(n^2) - \bigg(q - 1\bigg)\bigg(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$=q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q - 1)n^2.$$
Dividing both sides by $qn^2$, we get
$$I(n^2) - \frac{2(q-1)}{q} = \frac{I(n^2)}{q^{k+1}} > \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{2(q-1)}{q},$$
which implies that
$$I(n^2) > \bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} + 1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg).$$
**QED.**

To illustrate the improved bound:

**(1)** Unconditionally, we have
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q-1)}{q} \geq \frac{8}{5} = 1.6.$$

**(2)** Under the assumption that $k=1$:
$$I(n^2) > 2\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{q}\bigg)\bigg(1 + \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^2\bigg) \geq \frac{208}{125} = 1.664.$$

**(3)** However, it is known that under the assumption $k=1$, we actually have
$$I(q^k) = 1 + \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{6}{5} \implies I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \geq \frac{5}{3} = 1.\overline{666}.$$

Here are my questions:

> > **(A)** Is it possible to improve further on the unconditional lower bound for $I(n^2)$?

> > **(B)** If the answer to Question **(A)** is **YES**, my next question is "*How*"?

I did notice that
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q}+\frac{2}{q(q+1)}=I(n^2)=\frac{2q}{q+1}$$
when $k=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to come up with an improved lower bound for $I(n^2)$, albeit in terms of $q$ and $n$:

We write
$$I(n^2) - \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} = \frac{I(n^2)}{q^{k+1}} = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{1}{qn^2} > \frac{1}{qn^2},$$
from which it follows that
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{qn^2}.$$

This improved lower bound for $I(n^2)$, which does not contain $k$, can then be used to [produce an upper bound](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07697) for $k$.

Comment: I think
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{qn^2}$$
also improves on
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \frac{57}{20},$$
which by [Lemma II.2, page 1 of this conference paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1548.pdf), "would be equivalent to showing that there are no odd perfect numbers of the form $5n^2$, which would be a very major result".

Comment: Details for the argument in the [preceding comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382050/improving-the-lower-bound-in2-frac2q-1q-when-qk-n2-is-an-odd-p#comment1089494_404066) are in this [recent MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464635).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to further refine the improved lower bound for $I(n^2)$:

Write
$$I(n^2)=\frac{2}{I(q^k)}=\frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1}=\frac{2q^{k+1} (q - 1)}{q(q^{k+1} - 1)}=\bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{1}{q^{k+1}-1}\bigg).$$
Now use, for instance,
$$q^{k+1} - \frac{1}{q^2} > q^{k+1} - 1$$
to obtain
$$I(n^2)=\bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{1}{q^{k+1}-1}\bigg)>\bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q^{k+1} - \frac{1}{q^2}}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\Bigg(1 + \frac{q^2}{q^{k+3} - 1}\Bigg).$$

Note that
$$\bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(1 + \frac{q^2}{q^{k+3} - 1}\bigg) - \bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)=\frac{2(q-1)}{q^{k+2} (q^{k+3} - 1)}>0$$
since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

In fact, this method shows that there are *infinitely* many ways to refine the improved lower bound
$$I(n^2) > \bigg(\frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1}+1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg).$$

It remains to be seen whether there is a refined (improved) lower bound that is independent of $k$ (and therefore expressed entirely in terms of $q$).